# Loop through range and clear contents of 8 cells below the cell being evaluated

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through cells $C$29 to $G$29 and if the cells contain an empty space I want to clear the contents of the 8 cells below. For example if $G$29 is empty, I want to clear the contents in $G$30:$G$37. I have attached code below. But I believe there is something wrong with the .ClearContents line, something to do with the way I am attempting to reference relatively. Thank you!

Best,
M

```
Sub Hide_Financing()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Sheet2.Range("$C$29:$G$29")
    If r.Value = "" Then
        Sheet2.Range(r.Address & ":" & r.Offset(rowOffset:=8).Address).ClearContents
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It isn't doing anything when I attempt to run the macro. I haven't set it up with a worksheet change yet as I haven't been able to get this to clear the contents. I think my relative reference is wrong.

Comment: If you put a line break on `Sheet2.Range(r.Address & ":" & r.Offset(rowOffset:=8).Address).ClearContents` (you can put your cursor there and hit F9 on your keyboard), then put `?r.Address`  in the immediate pane and then `? r.Offset(rowOffset:=8).Address`, do you get your expected cell addresses returned?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean with the line break and the pane.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/immediate-window) might help. Alternatively you can use the `Debug.Print` statement in your code to output to the immediate pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me. In your code, nowhere you've set the value of "sheet2". Have you set it correctly? The rest of your code is right.
Another question, are you sure that you have cleared at least one cell in the range "$C$29:$G$29" ?

Comment: `Sheet2` is most likely the *codename* for Sheet2 (It is by default and I'd assume it's not been changed - but may have been!)

Comment: Yeah I screwed up on the Sheet name, it was Sheet1 I needed it for and not Sheet2

Comment: @mjhol Easy mistake to make! Even easier to fix!

Comment: Good experience! Good luck :))

Answer (score 0):

I've written this to provide more of an *answer*, as the current one is more of a comment and doesn't really provide a direct solution (it's ambiguous and implied that the `Sheet2` isn't declared anywhere which is your problem (which is not necessarily correct as Sheet2 is the code name for Worksheets("Sheet2") by default, so you should avoid variables with these types of name anyway).

When ***my code doesn't do anything*** you should take [basic debugging steps](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) (that's just one of many places on the web explaining how to debug - use your search engine to your advantage!).

From looking at your code, there is no syntax problems and it all seems like it *should* work, so, read it out loud to yourself.

You determined you were referencing cells on `Sheet2` instead of `Sheet1` which is something that really only you can establish as you are the only one that knows where you want to manipulate your data.

---

To summarize the key points here:

1. Use the [Rubber Duck debugging method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)
2. Debug your code.

You'd be surprised how many problems you can resolve by reading your code out loud to someone or something.

To debug your code, you can do things like use the `Debug.Print` statement. 
I'd add it to your code like so:

```
For Each r In Sheet2.Range("$C$29:$G$29")
    If r.Value = "" Then
        Debug.Print r.Address 
        Debug.Print r.Offset(rowOffset:=8).Address
    End If
Next r
```

Now for your applciation, you'd expect something like this in the immediate window:

```
$C$29
$C$37
```

But depending on your values on `Sheet2` if any, you'd likely see this:

That is blank on purpose, because you were referencing the wrong sheet - Or you might have seen some other unexpected cell references of course depending on your sheet2 values.

I'd assume, you would have realised pretty quickly that you should be checking `Sheet1` instead of `Sheet2` by doing both of these - of course it's not a guaranteed solution every time - some things just don't make sense and that's what communities like SO are for! - but it works more than you'd think it would for these kinds of things.